# MySQL export to Powershell

Tags: mysql, powershell, mysql-workbench

I have been using this code for almost 2 years to export mysql query into a csv file but as at 3 days now my export generates an error(Attached below) whenever I try to export  data from MySQL into the CSV file.

```
#Start-Process "$psHome\powershell.exe" -Verb Runas -ArgumentList '-command "Get-Service"'
###PROMPT USER FOR DETAILS
Param(
[Parameter(
Mandatory = $true,
ParameterSetName = '',
ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
[string]$Query
)

##END####

$MySQLAdminUserName = 'root'
$MySQLAdminPassword = 'Luke@2023'
$MySQLDatabase = 'mgdb23'
$MySQLHost = 'localhost'
$ConnectionString = "server=" + $MySQLHost + ";port=3306;uid=" + $MySQLAdminUserName + ";pwd=" + $MySQLAdminPassword + ";database="+$MySQLDatabase
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("MySql.Data") 
$mysql = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection($ConnectionString)
$mysql.Open()
$sqlquery1 = "SELECT
DISTINCT upper(personnel_employee.emp_code) as Employee_ID,
upper(personnel_employee.first_name)as First_Name,
upper(personnel_employee.last_name) as Last_Name,

date_format(att_payloadbase.att_date,'%Y/%m/%d') as Att_Date ,
dayname(att_payloadbase.att_date) as Week_Day,
if(weekday(att_payloadbase.att_date)IN(5,6) ,'Weekend','') as Exception,
IF(att_holiday.alias = '', IFNULL(att_holiday.alias,0), IFNULL(att_holiday.alias,0))as Holiday,
att_timeinterval.alias as TimeTable,
round((att_payloadbase.duration)/60,2) as Duration,
date_format(att_payloadbase.check_in,'%Y/%m/%d %T') as Check_In,
date_format(att_payloadbase.check_out,'%Y/%m/%d %T')as Check_Out,
round((att_payloadbase.duty_duration)/60,2) as Duty_Duration,
att_payloadbase.work_day,
date_format(att_payloadbase.clock_in,'%Y/%m/%d %T') as Clock_In,
date_format(att_payloadbase.clock_out,'%Y/%m/%d %T') as Clock_Out,
round((att_payloadbase.total_time)/60,2) as Total_Time,
round((att_payloadbase.actual_worked)/60,2) as Actual_WT,

CASE WHEN att_holiday.alias != '' THEN 480
WHEN dayname(att_payloadbase.att_date) in('Saturday','Sunday') THEN att_payloadbase.total_worked= 1
ELSE round((att_payloadbase.total_worked)/60,0)
END  AS Total_WT,

round((att_payloadovertime.normal_ot)/60,0) as Normal_OT,
round((att_payloadovertime.weekend_ot)/60,0) as Weekend_OT,
round((att_payloadovertime.holiday_ot)/60,0) as Holiday_OT,
round((att_payloadovertime.total_ot)/60,0) as Total_OT
FROM
att_payloadbase

inner JOIN personnel_employee ON att_payloadbase.emp_id = personnel_employee.id
left JOIN att_timeinterval ON att_payloadbase.timetable_id = att_timeinterval.id
left JOIN att_holiday ON att_payloadbase.att_date = att_holiday.start_date

left JOIN att_payloadovertime ON att_payloadbase.overtime_id = att_payloadovertime.uuid
  WHERE date_format(att_date,'%Y%m%d') = date_format('$Query','%Y%m%d')
  AND personnel_employee.status <100"

$req = New-Object Mysql.Data.MysqlClient.MySqlCommand($sqlquery1,$mysql)
$dataAdapter = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter($req)
$dataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$dataAdapter.Fill($dataSet, "Query1") | Out-Null
# Get the date
$DateStamp = (Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMddHHmmss");
#$Month = Get-Date.AddMonths(-1).ToString('MMM');

$filename = "C:/DataExchange/Attendance/Extra/Time_Card_$Query.csv"

$dataSet.Tables["Query1"] | Export-Csv -path $filename  -NoTypeInformation;
```

This the error code I get whenever I try the export

> Exception calling "Fill" with "2" argument(s): "Table 'mgdb23.att_payloadtimecard' doesn't exist"
> At C:\Scripts\Attendance_Report_By_Date - Copy.ps1:65 char:1

- $dataAdapter.Fill($dataSet, "Query1") | Out-Null
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MySqlException
  ```

Export-Csv : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null.
At C:\Scripts\Attendance_Report_By_Date - Copy.ps1:72 char:29

- ... et.Tables["Query1"] | Export-Csv -path $filename  -NoTypeInformation;
- ```
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Export-Csv], ParameterBindingValidationException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ExportCsvCommand

Any idea as to how I can solve this issue??

I run this code below in MySQL workbench and I got the result that I needed but combined with the powershell script give me the above error.

```
SELECT
DISTINCT upper(personnel_employee.emp_code) as Employee_ID,
upper(personnel_employee.first_name)as First_Name,
upper(personnel_employee.last_name) as Last_Name,

date_format(att_payloadbase.att_date,'%Y/%m/%d') as Att_Date ,
dayname(att_payloadbase.att_date) as Week_Day,
if(weekday(att_payloadbase.att_date)IN(5,6) ,'Weekend','') as Exception,
IF(att_holiday.alias = '', IFNULL(att_holiday.alias,0), IFNULL(att_holiday.alias,0))as Holiday,
att_timeinterval.alias as TimeTable,
round((att_payloadbase.duration)/60,2) as Duration,
date_format(att_payloadbase.check_in,'%Y/%m/%d %T') as Check_In,
date_format(att_payloadbase.check_out,'%Y/%m/%d %T')as Check_Out,
round((att_payloadbase.duty_duration)/60,2) as Duty_Duration,
att_payloadbase.work_day,
date_format(att_payloadbase.clock_in,'%Y/%m/%d %T') as Clock_In,
date_format(att_payloadbase.clock_out,'%Y/%m/%d %T') as Clock_Out,
round((att_payloadbase.total_time)/60,2) as Total_Time,
round((att_payloadbase.actual_worked)/60,2) as Actual_WT,

CASE WHEN att_holiday.alias != '' THEN 480
WHEN dayname(att_payloadbase.att_date) in('Saturday','Sunday') THEN att_payloadbase.total_worked= 1
ELSE round((att_payloadbase.total_worked)/60,0)
END  AS Total_WT,

round((att_payloadovertime.normal_ot)/60,0) as Normal_OT,
round((att_payloadovertime.weekend_ot)/60,0) as Weekend_OT,
round((att_payloadovertime.holiday_ot)/60,0) as Holiday_OT,
round((att_payloadovertime.total_ot)/60,0) as Total_OT
FROM
att_payloadbase

inner JOIN personnel_employee ON att_payloadbase.emp_id = personnel_employee.id
left JOIN att_timeinterval ON att_payloadbase.timetable_id = att_timeinterval.id
left JOIN att_holiday ON att_payloadbase.att_date = att_holiday.start_date

left JOIN att_payloadovertime ON att_payloadbase.overtime_id = att_payloadovertime.uuid
  WHERE date_format(att_date,'%Y%m%d') = date_format('$Query','%Y%m%d')
  AND personnel_employee.status <100
```

Comment: "but as at 3 days now my export generates an error"  What did you change to your code 3 days ago ?

Comment: Are you sure your powershell code and your mysql workbench connects to the same database? The table nam e referred to in the error message does not occur in your sql queries. Perhaps it is referenced by a view, but we cannot see that.

Comment: From $dataAdapter.Fill($dataSet, "Query1")  To : $dataAdapter.Fill($dataSet, $sqlquery1)  You have two queries.  One passed as a parameter to method and one set inside the function.  Not sure which one you want to use.  The other is $Query

Comment: @Luuk I haven't made any changes to the codes it just stopped working after some system updates were done. The script is being run on Windows Server 2022.